# Can I have multiple statements in a native query in JPA 2

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa, plsql

I want to execute the following query to conditionally drop a temporary table.

```
String dropSql = "BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE " + tmpTblName + "';" +
    " EXCEPTION" +
    " WHEN OTHERS THEN" +
    " IF SQLCODE!=-942 THEN" +
    " RAISE;" +
    " END IF;" +
    " END";
```

And then execute it as a native query like this:

```
JPA.em().createNativeQuery(dropSql)
            .executeUpdate();
```

However, JPA will not let me or rather, the oracle db won't. Apparently the ; get escaped or misinterpreted somehow.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 120:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
```

Will I have to live with using separate queries to achieve my goal or is there some trick to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed a semicolon after the `END` block finally.

```
String dropSql = "BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE " + tmpTblName + "';" +
    " EXCEPTION" +
    " WHEN OTHERS THEN" +
    " IF SQLCODE!=-942 THEN" +
    " RAISE;" +
    " END IF;" +
    " END;";
```

Comment: You are right. Seems as though jpa is inconsistent. When there's only one statement there should not be a semi-colon at the end.

Comment: Actually SQL dont need it but a PL/SQL needs it.